# Adding a SUM statement increases run time way too much, is there a better method?

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table with invoice payments, which can be partial or full. I am comparing this calculated field to the total amount of the invoice. I have it twice in the query, once in the Select statement and again in the Where clause. Even if I remove one so it's only in either the Where or the Select, it takes more than an hour to run. If I remove the SUM entirely, it takes 10 seconds to run.

Is there a better method to get the sum? Should I use an index view? A temp table? Note that an invoice number is unique only to a vendor, not unique in general. The initial FROM is a view, if this makes a difference.

```
select distinct
transdate,
invoicedate,
PAY.OrderAccount,
v.VendorName, 
invoiceamountmst,
(select sum(PAY1.settleamountcur) from [VIEW_INVOICE_PAYMENT] PAY1 where PAY.INVOICEID=PAY1.INVOICEID and PAY.OrderAccount=PAY1.OrderAccount) as "InvoiceSUM",
settleamountcur,
Currencycodeinvoice,
PAY.Description,
Voucher
from VIEW_INVOICE_PAYMENT PAY
inner join INVOICE on INVOICE_DOC_NO =invoiceid
JOIN VENDOR V on PAY.OrderAccount=v.VendorAccount
where TRANSDATE is not null
and (select sum(PAY1.settleamountcur) from [VIEW_INVOICE_PAYMENT] PAY1 where PAY.INVOICEID=PAY1.INVOICEID and PAY.OrderAccount=PAY1.OrderAccount)=total_cost_on_invoice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, when I refer to 'that select', I'm referring to the sub-query in the middle  `select sum(pay1.settlamountcur) ...`

Note that aliases in 'that select' looks a little strange e.g., `select sum(PAY1.settleamountcur) from [VIEW_INVOICE_PAYMENT] AX1`. Where does the PAY1 alias come from? I may have missed something. If that's a typo in your code, it could be doing bad things (if it even runs). Assuming it's not, however...

For your broader problem, I believe that it will be running that select statement once for every row being returned by your overall table. Indeed, it may be doing it more often, depending on when it's doing your filtering in the execution plan.

Note I'm assuming SQL Server in this answer - but it should apply to other databases as well.

A couple of options

1. Instead of referring to the view, instead bring the tables into your current query and modify the query as such
2. Try removing aggregation from the subquery, and instead do it over the whole data set  etc e.g., GROUP BY relevant fields, sum across relevant fields. This can be combined with option 1.
3. Put the sub-query as a CTE, or a sub-query within the FROM component. This may make it use it as a single table rather than running many times (or it may not)
4. (Sometimes my preferred option for large tables) Get the relevant data from the view into a temporary table first e.g.,

```
SELECT INVOICEId, OrderAccount, SUM(settleamountcur) AS total_settleamountcur
    INTO #Temp
    FROM [VIEW_INVOICE_PAYMENT] 
    GROUP BY INVOICEId, OrderAccount

-- Add any where/having clauses you can to filter
-- Consider creating temp table first with primary key, making joins easier for SQL Server
```

Then use the #Temp table instead of that select sub-query.

Comment: First of all, thanks for responding. You're right, I generalized the query when posting here and forgot to update the alias. Edited that now (AX1 changed to PAY1). Also, yes SQL server.

Comment: For point 2, I'm not sure what you mean, maybe I'm misunderstanding. The where clause in the subquery is required (as far as I know) to make sure I'm taking the sum of a single invoice/vendor combination. Without the where clause, I'll just get the sum of all payments, repeated each row.

Comment: I'll take a look into temp tables at your suggestion. I'm not super comfortable with them but hoping it will speed things up. Though if you drop the where clause, it will take a SUM of the entire table VIEW_INVOICE_PAYMENT instead of each invoice. So I still worry that it will take as long to populate the temp table. Will find out

Comment: Update... I made the query without any SUM statements into a temp table (had to add invoiceID column so that the main query would later work). I then added the sum statement as I had originally, replacing the sub table with the temp table.. and it ran in a matter of seconds. So this is definitely the way to go!

So I will make a SP I guess, which creates the table and then runs this query:

'select (select sum(PAY.settleamountcur) from #MXP_AX_TEMP PAY where TEMP.INVOICEID=PAY.INVOICEID and TEMP.OrderAccount=PAY.OrderAccount) as "InvoiceSUM",
* from #MXP_AX_TEMP TEMP'

Comment: Excellent. I was working on examples of Option 2 etc and was running into problems understanding groupings and meaning of exactly what you were trying to do. But if you have a good solution, I don't need to!